# I am having some problems with my css and html file

Tags: html, css

This is my html code:

```
<html>
<head>

<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}"></style>

</head>



<body>

   <h2 align="centre">Hello!</h2>
   <h1>Hello Again!</h1>

   <p>this is a paragraph!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

this is css code:

```
body {
    background: #fafafa;
    color: red;
}
header {
    color: blue
}
```

this is python code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template("base.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

just one url but its still not working
i am not a html or css "expert" so i need
some help, and i dont have any friends so stackoverflow was the only option

i also saw many people use `<link>` tag instead of `<style>` idk the difference
and google is showing something else, any help would be appriciated!

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: Maybe problem is in file structures.
[Look this answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22260791/4025741)

Answer (score 2):

Here, I Sorted The Linkings Between Files...

---

This Is The Required [Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2F58.png)

Here Is The **main.css**,

```
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  color: red;
}

header {
  color: blue;
}
```

Here Is The **base.html**,

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}"></link>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Hello!</h2>
  <h1>Hello Again!</h1>
  <p>this is a paragraph!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is **app.py**,

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
# from flask import request


app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')


@app.route('/')
# @app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template("base.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And [The Result of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MfZb.png)

Comment: You Have Not Used Any header tag in HTML That's Why No Blue Color Is Shown!!

Answer (score 1):

To include an external stylesheet, you can use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` where styles.css is the name of the stylesheet. This should appear within the `<head>` tags. The `<style>` tag can be used for internal styles such as:

```
<style>
    body {
        background: #fafafa;
        color: red;
    }
    header {
        color: blue
    }
</style>
```

in your HTML. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) has a page explaining the different ways to include CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python, but why are you trying to get your css file using 'href' tag when you can use 'src' like this

```
<head>
    <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="yourfile.css"></style>
</head>
```

where src can be absolute path to your file ('c:/yourproject/yourfile.css') or, better, relative path so if you have html and css in the same path you can simply use your css file name?

Comment: the way `flask` is different with normal `html` and `css` , in this case , `flask` is the server which will manage `html` and other file..so it is needed to use `href` by a `<link>`