# CSS File not being detected

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, flask

My CSS file attached to my python code isn't working, and I can't seem to figure out why since there are no errors and I've tried multiple ways of doing this.

Structure:

```
app{
    |app
        |templates
            |public
                |index.html
    |env
    |static
        |css
            |styles.css
```

I've attached it to index.html with
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">`

and in my python file I used

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
        return render_template("public/index.html")
```

Everything works perfectly find but the CSS doesn't work on the page:
**style.css**

```
body {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your project structure, the `static` sub-folder is outside the `app` folder. Consider adding it at the same location as `templates`.

```
project
 | -- app
       | -- templates/
       | -- static/
```

Your `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to put the filename parameter to: `filename='/static/css/styles.css', and see if it works.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Though I have noticed when I look in chrome sources, it seems to be generating its own file instead of detecting the styles.css file which is already in the folder.  https://gyazo.com/15ec94b4542957f1c51ee815caa16d2e

Comment: Weird. This should help [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259847/application-not-picking-up-css-file-flask-python). I think you are missing `type="text/css"`, that seems to be the issue.

Comment: I've already tried that, failing to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

`styles.css` or `style.css`?
Check the css file name!

If that is a typo in your question and not in your main code, try reloading your page using `Ctrl + Shift + R`.

Comment: The names are both styles.css, error in my comment. I reload my page everytime it's updated in debug mode. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I cannot see any error in here. Are you sure is `<link rel="stylesheet"...>` tag inside the head tags of the html file?