# Flask, url_for() not linking static file

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm having trouble linking my static "css" file. When I run the code I only get my basic html and not the css. When I use the html  element all of my css code work fine. Here is my code:

```css
h1 {
  padding: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.header {
  padding: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.sidebar div {
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
}

.body-text {
  margin-right: 150px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>


<body>
  <h1>Header</h1>


  <div class="sidebar">
    <div>Menu Item 1</div>
    <div>Menu Item 2</div>
    <div>Menu Item 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="body-text">
    <!-- body content -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my python code also in case that is causing a problem:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['ENV'] = 'development'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['TESTING'] = True

app.static_folder = 'static'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('base.html')

@app.route('/<name>')
def user(name):
    return f"Hello {name}!"

@app.route('/admin')
def admin():
    return redirect(url_for('index', name='Admin'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Thanks for any help. Sorry if the code is messy, I'm a rookie :).

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ;) If you're getting an error, please post the full error message. Otherwise, does [this OS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22260791/10753968) help?

Comment: linkage to css looks okay, may I know what problem you have noticed? if css load fails, then you will see 404 on network tab of dev tools.

Comment: Your code looks good. May I ask where your `style.css` is located?

Comment: This could be a browser cache related issue, so maybe try resetting/deleting the cache on your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answer given above, this might also occur sometimes if your browser has already cached the CSS file. You can force your browser to refresh the contents using `Ctrl+f5` on your keyboard each time you add new code in your `style.css` file.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with the structure of your application. Consider this structure:

```py
project_folder
   | --- app/
          | --- templates/
                 | --- index.html
          | --- static/
                 | --- style.css
```

The templates sub-folder should be at the same location as the static sub-folder. Your link should work just with this structure.

```py
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
```